# JSF (PrimeFaces) radio button behavior when space bar used to activate

Tags: jsf, focus

I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 to render a radio button group for gender.  This is for an internal network so will only run on IE11 browsers in compatibility mode.  When I select one of the radio buttons by pressing space the button is correctly activated but I don't know where the focus has gone.  If I press TAB I got to the first item that I set the tabindex for, but if I press SHIFT-TAB focus does not go to the previous element that I set the tabindex on but goes to a button that I did not set the tabindex on and is also not the first or last element in the default tab order (it is not the first or last element added to the page).

The element before the gender radio buttons is included, the calendar button is what is getting selected with SHIFT-TAB The JSF (with sensitive information removed) is as follows:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <h:outputText value="#{enr['birth.date']}"/>*:
   </td>
   <td>
      <p:calendar id="birthDate" value="#{II.birthdate}" mode="popup" showOn="button" popupIconOnly="true" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" mask="9999-99-99" maxdate="#{UserBean.currentDate}" yearrange="c-120" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{enr['missing.required.field']}: #{enr['birth.date']}" tabindex="4"/>
      <p:tooltip for="birthDate" value="yyyy-MM-dd" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <h:outputText value="#{enr['other.last.names']}"/> / <h:outputText value="#{enr['maiden.name']}"/>
   </td>
   <td>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" title="Icon Only" tabindex="5" immediate="true">
         <f:ajax listener="#{II.addOtherName()}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields"/>
      </p:commandButton>
      <h:dataTable id="otherNameFields" value="#{II.otherNames}" var="otherNameField">
         <h:column size="30" maxlength="50">
            <h:inputText value="#{otherNameField.otherName}" tabindex="6">
               <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{II.populateName()}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields" />
            </h:inputText>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Icon Only" immediate="true" tabindex="6">
               <f:ajax listener="#{II.deleteOtherName(otherNameField)}" immediate="true" render="otherNameFields" />
            </p:commandButton>
         </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <h:outputText value="#{enr['gender']}"/>*:
   </td>
   <td>
      <p:selectOneRadio value="#{II.gender}" tabindex="7" required="true" requiredMessage="#{enr['missing.required.field']}: #{enr['gender']}" style="border-style: none !important;">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="#{enr['male']}"/>
     <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{enr['female']}"/>
      </p:selectOneRadio>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I also did a plain non-JSF version for comparison which works as expected so I am certain the problem is in the JSF.

Plain HTML below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Non Index:<input type="text" /></p>
        <p>Index #200:<input tabindex="200" type="text" /></p>
        <p><input name="gender" tabindex="201" id="gender_male" type="radio" value="2" />Male</p>
        <p><input name="gender" tabindex="201" id="gender_female" type="radio" value="1" />Female</p>
        <p>Index #202:<input tabindex="202" type="text" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I

Comment: Turns out we are using a buggy implementation of Websphere - tested in Tomcat and all was well.

Comment: _"I also did a plain non-JSF version for comparison which works as expected so I am certain the problem is in the JSF."_ In my opinion a wrong assumption... Most likely the compatibility mode of IE is the problem that causes it to not correctly work with jQuery and PrimeFaces. And `f:ajax` inside an `p:commandButton` is strange to since it by default is already ajax enabled. And a newer version of PrimeFaces might also have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by using plain JSF version of the `selectOneRadio`, ie:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{II.gender}" tabindex="7" required="true" requiredMessage="#{enr['missing.required.field']}: #{enr['gender']}" style="border-style: none !important;">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="#{enr['male']}"/>
     <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{enr['female']}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

where:

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

Comment: This is not the (best) solution to your problem. A possible (more likely) cause is _" IE11 browsers in compatibility mode."_ Just make sure you force them (and that can be done per application, even per page if you want) into standards compliant mode. And a newer version of PF might also have helped. So this sounds more like a suboptimal workaround then a fix

Comment: Thanks for the input Kukeltje - my deadline does not allow me to put much more time into this but I will certainly try your suggestions and if they work squeeze them into the next patch :)